# Doctrine2 and persistence : cascading error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

To make it quick, I use Doctrine2 on entities.

One of my entities, User, possess a Contact through a 1 to 1 relationship.

I create both of them at the same time, persist the "children of the user" (here, his contact) and then proceed to persist the user itself. I do that very generically :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($object->getChildren()); //object->getChildren() is the Contact here
$em->persist($object); // $object is my User
$em->flush();
```

The persistence of the contact worked once (I don't really know how or why) but since then everytime I persist the User that way, it fails, giving me this error message :

A new entity was found through the relationship 'Aurae\UserBundle\Entity\User#contact' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Aurae\UserBundle\Entity\Contact@00000000554b2adc000000007fa05d30. 
Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Aurae\UserBundle\Entity\Contact#__toString()' to get a clue.

I tried declaring cascade persist in the User, but it didn't change anything.

What's the correct way to persist the Contact with the User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cascade={"persist"}` on the Contact declaration in User solved the problem. Case closed.